# mysql select categories e subcategories from the same table

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have the following table called "products":

```
id INT 11
product_name VARCHAR 255
category VARCHAR 255
subcategory VARCHAR 255
subsubcategory VARCHAR 255
```

I would like to read all categories, sub-categories and sub-sub-categories (only once each category) in one single query.

For now I have the following query, but im not sure it's working:

```
SELECT category, subcategory, subsubcategory FROM products WHERE category != '' GROUP by category, subcategory, subsubcategory ORDER by category ASC, subcategory ASC, subsubcategory ASC
```

The output should be something like:

```
clothes (main category)
clothes > pants (sub category)
clothes > pants > man (sub sub category)
clothes > pants > woman
clothes > skirt
jewelry
jewelry > necklace
```

Comment: Your select query doesn't match your table definition. Please fix them.

Comment: Your expected output is confusing. What do you want to achieve? Why you need such table structure? I think the answers to those questions will be useful to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select category as rendered from products
union all 
select concat(category, ' > ', subcategory) from products
union all 
select concat(category, ' > ', subcategory, ' > ', subsubcategory) from products
order by rendered
```